# Predicate returning false

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble with the following predicate:

```
treeToList(void, []).
treeToList(arbol(X, HI1, HD1), L) :- 
   treeToList(HI1, L1),
   treeToList(HD1, L2),
   append(L1, [X|L2], L).
    
maximumInList([X], X).
maximumInList([A|L], X) :-
   maximumInList(L,X1), 
   (A > X1 -> X = A; X = X1).
    
maxNodeInTree(arbol, N) :-
   treeToList(arbol, L), 
   maximumInList(L, N).
```

TreeToList gets a tree and returns a list with all of its nodes. Meanwhile maximumInList gets a list and returns the maximum element in the list.

Both of these predicates work fine individually, however the last one, `maxNodeInTree`, is supposed to first get the list L using `treeToList` which then will be passed to `maximumInList` and it'll return the maximum element in the whole tree. And yet Prolog returns `false`.

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the last predicate (`arbol` instead of `Arbol`). Try:

```
maxNodeInTree(Arbol, N) :-
   treeToList(Arbol, L), 
   maximumInList(L, N).
```